# MYSQL how to insert with next column ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
Row
ID | name | prev_row | next_row
-------------------------------
0  | test | NULL     | NULL
1  | test | NULL     | NULL
2  | test | NULL     | NULL
3  | test | NULL     | NULL
4  | test | NULL     | NULL
5  | test | NULL     | NULL
```

--

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO row (name, prev_row, next_row) VALUES (:name, :prevRow, :nextRow);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $stmt->bindParam(":name", $row->getName());
   $stmt->bindParam(":prevRow", ????????????);
   $stmt->bindParam(":nextRow", ????????????);

   $stmt->execute();
}
```

How would I populate the previous and next row parameters?
The previous row is the ID of the row inserted before the current row in the for loop. The next row is the ID of the row that will be inserted AFTER the current row in the for loop.

I know that I could do this for the previous row:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO row (name, prev_row, next_row) VALUES (:name, :prevRow, :nextRow);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $stmt->bindParam(":name", $row->getName());
   $stmt->bindParam(":prevRow", $pdo->lastInsertID());
   $stmt->bindParam(":nextRow", ????????????);

   $stmt->execute();
}
```

But I have no idea how the next row can be obtained since it has not been created yet.

Comment: Define 'previous' and 'next'

Comment: @Strawberry Updated answer

Comment: So what's $rows ?

Comment: It's just an array of objects. It's not what is important. What's important is how I am able to access the previous and next assertion in the database. Especially since the next row hasn't been inserted so it does not have an ID yet.

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: Well, the short answer is: you cannot insert the next row's id in the insert becayse the next row's id is not known. What you can do after the insertion is that you run an update that gets the next row's id.

Comment: @Shadow Is there any way to know if the previous insert ID is from the current for loop session and some some insert earlier in the code?

Comment: Last insert id is session (connection) specific, so unless you are sharing the connection with another script or your current script does some parallel insertion,, you will be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant get next id, what you can do is do an INSERT without :nextRow (null, or some other value just temporary), store the id of inserted row and in next loop run insert new row and also update the previous one with this new row id as a nextRow.

Something like this:

```
<?php

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO row (name, prev_row, next_row) VALUES (:name, :prevRow, :nextRow");

$stmtUpdate = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE row SET next_row = :nextRow WHERE id = :id");

$previousId = null;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   // insert current row without nextRow
   $stmt->bindParam(":name", $row->getName());
   $stmt->bindParam(":prevRow", $pdo->lastInsertID());
   $stmt->bindParam(":nextRow", null);
   $stmt->execute();

   if ($previousId) {
     // update previous row with this rows id as its nextRow
     $stmtUpdate->bindParam(":nextRow", $pdo->lastInsertId());
     $stmtUpdate->bindParam(":id", $previousId);
     $stmtUpdate->execute();
   }

   $previousId = $pdo->lastInsertID();
}
```

This also makes sense as the last row you insert wont have `nextRow`